# Is it possible to manually 3D print on an uneven surface?

Tags: extrusion, recycling

I chipped off a bit of my otherwise perfectly usable laptop battery and would like to rebuild it. Consider the following picture:

[image: chipped off battery connector of a Thinkpad x270 battery]

Now compare it to what is visible e.g. [here](https://www.batterybuy.co.uk/battery-lenovo/pic_big_Zoom/thinkpadx240-3cell-1.jpg). I'm curious if it's possible to point a few cameras from a different angle at the bad and manually operate a typical 3D printer (let's say, Creality Ender 3) so that it's me operating the extruder, not a program. Does it have any chance working on that uneven surface?

Comment: Frame challenge: Does the battery clip securely into place in the laptop and properly power it as is? If so, just leave it alone.

Comment: @FreeMan that's the problem - it doesn't clip without that missing piece. And when it disconnects, the laptop shuts down, instead of using the back-up battery because it's not disconnected the normal way.

Comment: That sucks. I asked because some batteries I've used have a latching mechanism that's totally separate from the electrical connections.

Answer (score 3):

In general, *maybe*. But you need to have plastics that will bond with each other (so you need to know what the existing surface is) and you need to have a clean unobstructed path for the nozzle to get where it needs to go.

In your specific case, this is a battery. Having a 200+ ˚C metal heater block and nozzle tip a few mm away from it, where any wrong move could puncture and short the battery, seems like a really bad idea. I would instead look at recreating the missing part with epoxy resin or something. You could 3D print a mold (note: apply a release agent to the surface!) for this, or you could just glob on more than you need and file the excess off.

If you have a steady hand, a 3D pen might also be an option, but the same concerns about "proximity to battery" as above apply.

Comment: Yeah, print separately and file to fit before glueing